# UnboundLocalError at /cart/slug/ local variable 'product' referenced before assignment

Tags: python, html, django, web-applications

I am trying to use a link to add items to a cart but it keeps saying that I am referencing the variable before it assigned.

```
views.py:
def view(request):
    cart = Cart.objects.all()[0]
    products = Product2.objects.all()
    context = {
    "cart": cart,
    "products": products
    }
    template = "cart/view.html"
    return render(request, template, context)

def update_cart(request, slug):
    cart = Cart.objects.all()[0]
    try:
        product = Product2.objects.get(slug = slug)
    except Product2.DoesNotExist:
        pass
    except:
        pass
    if not product in cart.products.all():
        cart.products.add(product)
    else:
        cart.products.remove(product)
    return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse("cart"))

models.py:

class Product2(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    price = models.IntegerField()
    slug = models.SlugField()

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name        


html:

{% for product in products %}
<div>
    <h1>{{ product.name }}:  ${{ product.price }}<a href='{% url "update_cart" product.slug %}' class ='pull-right'>Add to Cart</a></h1>
</div>
{% endfor %}
```

I had it working for a second but I created a new table in the database, changed the name where applicable, and now it doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

In `update_cart`, if an exception is raised during `product = Product2.objects.get(slug = slug)`, then `product` will not be defined and the line `if not product in cart.products.all()` will raise the `UnboundLocalError`.

You may fix this by only proceeding with the following code, which uses `product` if no exception was raised:

```
def update_cart(request, slug):
    cart = Cart.objects.all()[0]
    try:
        product = Product2.objects.get(slug = slug)
    except Product2.DoesNotExist:
        pass
    else:
        if not product in cart.products.all():
            cart.products.add(product)
        else:
            cart.products.remove(product)
    return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse("cart"))
```

The `else` clause to `try/except` here will only be executed if no exception was raised by the code inside `try`, meaning that you won't try to use `product` unless it has been successfully defined.

As a side note, I recommend avoiding the bare `except`, since this would mask any problems/interrupts that occur during execution of your code (see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54948548/what-is-wrong-with-using-a-bare-except)).